# Retrieve a table from DB using php and then choose a specific item

Tags: php, mysql

My header is probably ambiguous so i'm gonna explain it.

I have a table "books" in my database. I need to retrieve the table using php and then choose the book and comment about the book.

I got the retrieving part, a table with all my books is displayed.

I am stuck with selecting the book part.

Here is what i need to do:

1. Retrieve the table "books" from DB
2. Choose some book from that table (i.e. dropdown list etc)
3. Press submit and go to another page where I can leave a comment about that book
4. The comment must be recorded in DB

I just need help with selecting the book from the table. How to do it?

Comment: Show your tables structure and SQL code, you tried.

Comment: Do you mean `SELECT * FROM books WHERE ... ` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

let me assume you have a these rows in the table book
book_id(PI), name author

```
<form method="post" action="something.php">
<select name="book">
<?php
$stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT id,name,author FROM books");
if($stmt) {
$stmt->execute();
$result = $stmt->get_result();
while ($myrow = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
echo '<option value='.$myrow['book_id'].'>'.$name.' '.$author.'</option>';
}
//instead of $result you can also do
if($stmt) {
$stmt->execute();
$stmt->bind_result($id,$name,$author):
while ($stmt->fetch()) {
echo '<option...
}
?>
```

if you want both the id and name or all of the three go to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4420747/php-get-dropdownlist-select-option-value) link

if you want to select your books on certain criteria, for example lets say author=enid

then modify the query like this:

```
$stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT id,name,author FROM books WHERE author=?");
if($stmt) {
$stmt->bind_param("s",$input_name);
$stmt->execute();
.....
```

then at the something.php use the $_POST[''] to get the user inputs.
then u can make a form use a hidden value with a value= id of the book
make a comment box
use a submit button.
then in another table 'comments' u can have two rows comment_id(PI) book_id and comment

then use the insert query

```
$stmt=mysqli_prepare("insert into comments (book_id,comment) values (?,?)");
if($stmt) {
 $stmt->bind_param('is',$book_id,$comment);
$stmt->execute();
}
```

always remember to use $stmt->close() and $stmt->free() . how to do that will be answred by php.net